# Make a table of layouts jumping the line automatically

Tags: java, android

Is there some kind of class / method / technique that allows to automatically "jump the line" when the right side of the screen is reached when filling a layout ?

I have about 30 images and I want to put them in a table **without resizing** so for some screens each row should contain 6 images and maybe in a tablet maybe all can fit in a single row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roman Guy wrote a FlowLayout implementation live on stage during the devoxx 2010 , the video is available on parleys.com. Basically it's like a LinearLayout which goes on new line as soon as there is no more space. Not sure this is what you are looking for.